# Unable to unmarshal an object inside another object

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I have got an xml file:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:Data xmlns:ns1="http://vv.com/namespace">
         <Addr>Address 1</Addr1>
         <Locality>San Francisco</Locality>
         <Country>Japan</Country>
         <CountryCode>JP</CountryCode>
      </ns1:Data>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

AddressDto.java

```js
@XmlRootElement(name = "Data", namespace = "http://vv.com/namespace")
public class AddressDto implements Serializable
{
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private CountryDto country;

    public AddressDto()
    {
        super();
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Addr")
    public String getStreet1()
    {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet1(final String street1)
    {
        this.street = street1;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Locality")
    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(final String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public CountryDto getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }
    
    public void setCountry(final CountryDto country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

CountryDto file:

```js
public class CountryDto implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String code;

    public CountryDto()
    {
        super();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "CountryCode")
    public String getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(final String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Country")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When i run the code

```js
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddressDto.class);
Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
AddressDto emp = (AddressDto) un.unmarshal(response.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
return emp;
```

I am able to get the street and city in AddressDto object. But the field country is displaying as null...Any idea whats going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parser don't know what Country / CountryCode means. You defined only Addr and Locality as XmlElement inside your AddressDto class. Therefore you will get null.

You need to modify your xml to something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:Data xmlns:ns1="http://vv.com/namespace">
         <Addr>Address 1</Addr1>
         <Locality>San Francisco</Locality>
         <CountryDto>
             <Country>Japan</Country>
             <CountryCode>JP</CountryCode>
         </CountryDto>
      </ns1:Data>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And also modify your addressDto so **getCountry()** is XmlElement as well:

```
@XmlElement(name = "CountryDto")
public CountryDto getCountry()
{
    return country;
}
```

Now Country and CountryCode won't be null anymore

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin...I would not be able to make any changes in the xml schema as this service is being used by others applications too. Is there any way by which I could take the country and countrycode from the xml and map it to the corresponding fields in the CountryDto Object?

Comment: Sorry, I can't come up with the solution without changing xml schema :( hope someone more experience will help you...